# In Doom3's Engine, why did id use a CLASS_PROTOTYPE macro instead of adding variables in idClass

Tags: c++, macros, game-engine

I want to learn more about game engines so I started reading up Doom3's engine code. In this part of the code:

```
/*
================
CLASS_PROTOTYPE

This macro must be included in the definition of any subclass of idClass.
It prototypes variables used in class instanciation and type checking.
Use this on single inheritance concrete classes only.
================
*/
    #define CLASS_PROTOTYPE( nameofclass )                                  \
    public:                                                                 \
        static  idTypeInfo                      Type;                       \
        static  idClass                         *CreateInstance();  \
        virtual idTypeInfo                      *GetType() const;       \
        static  idEventFunc<nameofclass>        eventCallbacks[]
```

I don't understand why id included this macro for each class derived from idClass instead of just including these variables in the idClass itself. Can anybody explain the reasoning behind this?

Comment: This macro defines `static` fields which are shared between all instances of the particular class. Including them in the `idClass` base class would mean that all the derived classes would share exactly the same ids.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I thought inherited static variables would have unique instances for each derived class.